# can md5sum check ignore some warnings?

Tags: hashsum, checksum

When I run md5sum -c I get errors such as "No such file or directory". I only want checksum that did not match and ignore files that could not be read. --quiet gives me same result.

Comment: The man page mentions another option `--ignore-missing - don't fail or report status for missing files`.

Comment: that gives me "no file was verified" error. nothing else.